# Proving that we can chose 26 lines and 43 points so that every line contains eaxctly 7 points and every point belongs to exactly 4 lines

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The rpoblem consits in proving if we can define such 26 different lines and 43 different points, so that every line contains exactly 7 points and every point passes through 4 lines.

The issue for me is trying to translate this problem into graph theory language. I do not exactly understand what am I looking for in terms of graphs.

Comment: Line -- vertex, point -- a $K_{4,4}$ for all the 4 lines, 'pinned' by the point. So we count edges, $26\cdot 7\cdot 4\cdot \frac{1}{2}$ should be equal to ${4\choose 2}\cdot 43$, contradiction, QED.

Comment: Counting (point,line) incidence pairs both ways we get $26\times 7 = 182 \neq 43\times 4=172.$ Thus it does not exist.

Comment: Is it a problem "to prove" (as stated in title) or is it "prove or disprove" {as hinted in body of post)?

Comment: In graph theory language, is there a bipartite graph where one part has $26$ vertices, all of degree $7$, and the other part has $43$ vertices, all of degree $4$?